# Magento large attribute list - CSV Importing and Potential response time issues

Tags: magento, csv, import, attributes, load-time

I am relatively new to Magento and have a question around the CSV importing process and any effects that large attributes may have on the database / response times.

Each product on my shop may have up to 200 different colour variations as well as 6 or so size variations. What is the easiest way to import this? In other e-commerce solutions I have created a CSV file and added one line (per product) and comma seperated the vaiations in the appropriate field. However from what I can tell each variation in Magento must be on its own line, meaning my import file will be huge. Can anybody provide me with an easier solution?

Also what implications will my large attribute list have on load time?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you have to large catalog then you have to create custom script according to the your csv files.

Comment: if you can share some sample data csv then we can create a script accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to import by CSV file a large number of products I reccommend the use of this tool
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/
Magento Mass Importer
This tool is incredibly fast in respect of the standard Magento import.

The size (number of columns) of you CSV file depend also by the way you create the products.
To reduce the size I suggest to use the configurable product type instead of the
custom option.

Bye
Giuseppe